# Install stock firmware on my Galaxy S5 SM-900T

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I would like the correct info on how  to install stock firmware on my Galaxy S5 SM900T.  And what do I need to know about my phone before I do it. Like all the correct numbers so I do this correctly.
Thanks 
KPH

Comment: [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s5/SM-G900T/)

Answer (score 0):

Official website for downloading firmware [here](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s5/SM-G900T/).

For method of flashing, precautions and other requirements follow this [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-galaxy-s5/general/compilation-s5-g900t-stock-firmware-t3042400)

> 1) extract/unzip firmware file (should show as .tar)
>
> 2) download odin v3.09 or newer and extract
>
> 3) open odin
>
> 4) Reboot Phone in Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
>
> 5) Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
>
> 6) Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
>
> 7) Make sure re-partition is NOT ticked and keep odin default settings
>
> 8) Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes